# Visual Studio Code Insiders changes file permissions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running Visual Studio Code Insiders in Windows 10 and I have an Ubuntu VM that shares a Samba mounted directory. Whenever I'm editing (in windows) a shell script file (e.g. test.sh) and save it (on the ubuntu machine), it chances the files permission.
This seems to be a VSCode feature, since my extensions are all disabled and it still does that change. "Funny" thing that it only affected my shell scripts and bbappend files (yocto append recipes).

Can't find a reason for this. HELP!!!!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you're running Insiders, you should report this to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

After some investigation I came to a conclusion that this problem has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code, but rather with my Samba server configurations.
By default, Samba server configuration maps windows file permissions to linux as 744. So, to fix this, I added on Global Settings:

create mask = 0644

and

create directoy = 0644

also it is handly to not map the Archive bit by adding

map archive = no